# how to get products list by category name in nested set

Tags: php, mysql, nested, set

I have below sql for nested set, I need to display all products under electronics category and it's child categories

electronics -> portable electronics -> mp3 players -> flash

what should be the sql query to do this in mysql

```
--
-- Table structure for table `categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `left_node` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `right_node` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `categories`
--

INSERT INTO `categories` (`category_id`, `name`, `left_node`, `right_node`) VALUES
(1, 'electronics', 1, 20),
(2, 'televisions', 2, 9),
(3, 'tube', 3, 4),
(4, 'lcd', 5, 6),
(5, 'plasma', 7, 8),
(6, 'portable electronics', 10, 19),
(7, 'mp3 players', 11, 14),
(8, 'flash', 12, 13),
(9, 'cd players', 15, 16),
(10, '2 way radios', 17, 18);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `products`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

INSERT INTO `products` (`product_id`, `name`, `cat_id`) VALUES
(1, '20" TV', 3),
(2, '36" TV', 3),
(3, 'Super-LCD 42"', 4),
(4, 'Ultra-Plasma 62"', 5),
(5, 'Value Plasma 38"', 5),
(6, 'Power-MP3 5gb', 7),
(7, 'Ipod 4gb', 8),
(8, 'Porta CD', 9),
(9, 'Walkman', 9),
(10, 'Family Talk 360', 10);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `product_categories`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_categories` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `product_categories`
--

INSERT INTO `product_categories` (`product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 5),
(5, 5),
(6, 7),
(7, 8),
(8, 9),
(9, 9),
(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name, c.category_id, c.left_node, c.right_node, p.product_id, p.name
from categories c, products p
where c.category_id = p.category_id group by c.category_id
```

[image]

Comment: If new table introduced then how to achieve same results ?

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_categories` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `product_categories` (`product_id`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 3),
(2, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 5),
(5, 5),
(6, 7),
(7, 8),
(8, 9),
(9, 9),
(10, 10);

Comment: Sidhu can u explain me much more clearly if u don't mind...!!! And sidhu i have a suggestion for u. i.e go through foreign key relationship.

Comment: I have updated tables structure, SELECT p.*
FROM products as p
LEFT JOIN `product_categories` AS `pc` ON (`pc`.`product_id` = `p`.`product_id`)
WHERE pc.category_id IN (SELECT node.category_id 
FROM categories AS node, categories AS parent
WHERE node.left_node 
BETWEEN parent.left_node AND parent.right_node
AND parent.category_id = 6 ORDER BY node.left_node)

Comment: above query works fine, it used IN clause, I want to replace IN clause with JOINS how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p.* FROM product p,categories c WHERE p.category_id = c.category_id and p.category_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to get the rows you wanted.

```
SELECT categories.name, products.name
FROM categories
INNER JOIN products ON categories.category_id = products.category_id
WHERE categories.category_id = ?
```